# How to compare a new time duration with a stored duration and replace with the shorter of the two?

Tags: java, android, time

I want to keep a record for the shortest time taken to complete a game level.

I want to store it in SharedPreferences. Right now, I'm able to store and retrieve the time for each level and set that in a ListView, but I'm storing it in a String format like "00:00".

I'm using two int(s) (Minutes, Seconds) which increases by 1 every one second finally when level completes I store it like

```
String time = String.format("%02d", Minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", Seconds);
```

Then I store it in SharedPreferences. But I'm unable to compare if the most recent time taken to complete a level is shorter than the previously shortest time.

I only want to replace time if user takes less time than before for that particular level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store a timestamp instead. You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the time when the level was started and call that again when it finishes, get the difference and stored that as a long instead of a string.  You can then convert those milliseconds to seconds and minutes using

```
String.format("%02d %02d", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
);
```

Something like this

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long differenceTime = endTime - startTime;
            Log.d("TEST", String.format("%02d %02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(differenceTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(differenceTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(differenceTime))
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: Everything Is Done But, When I'm Trying To Convert Millis To Minutes It Returns 24807913, I tried TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis); Still It Returns Tme In This way, I tried int mins = (millis/1000) / 60; it still returns the same...

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example on how to use it.